# how to work around node.js dependencies?

Tags: node.js, rhino, emscripten

I'm trying to interpret a javascript program generated by emscripten with rhino, but apparently the generated code depends on features of node.js, not covered by rhino. I get:

```
js: "d.js", line 1: uncaught JavaScript runtime exception: TypeError: Cannot call method "slice" of null
```

Probably because of this:

```
Module["arguments"]=process["argv"].slice(2)
```

How can I prevent emscripten to depend on node.js features, or somehow provide them to rhino?

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but couldn't you just use node.js instead of rhino ? I'm not sure what the origin of your LLVM bitcode is, but I'm guessing the `process.argv` isn't going to be your only node dependency

Comment: @WillemD'haeseleer True, but it is the first error reported. I've tried to run this with rhinodo, but rhinodo does not seem to work at all. It is my old wish to see a C++ "hello world" program run in the JVM.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to use the new javascript implementation from java 8, Nashorn. Everything apparently works when using that. Also, the fact that emscripten-generated code does not work under rhino, is due to a bug.